# Sort String date in object

Tags: swift, sorting

I have table view, that have data like "from,To, Action, Date and description". now I'm getting the date as string format and I need to sort the messages by date from latest date to earlier date, I tried sort code but it sort just first two characters.
for ex: tSFDATE have strings "11/01/2010", "01/02/2010". the result will be

"01/02/2010", "11/01/2010".
so any solution to sort TrackObj by date

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! TrackingTableViewCell

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm:ss"


        let sortedArray = self.trackingListArr.sorted { dateFormatter.date(from: $0.tSFDATE!)! < dateFormatter.date(from: $1.tSFDATE!)! }


        let trackObj = sortedArray[indexPath.row]


            cell.lblFromValue.text = trackObj.fROMUSERAR!

            cell.lblToValue.text = trackObj.tOUSERAR!

            cell.lblPurpsValue.text = trackObj.tSFPURPOSEAR!

            cell.lblDateValue.text = trackObj.tSFDATE!

            cell.lblNoteValue.text = trackObj.tSFDESCRIPTION!

    return (cell)

}
```

here is the result image
[image]

Comment: use .compare for date comparison instead. something like date1.compare(date2) == .orderedAscending

Comment: @koropok can you give me the code because I tried it but I believe there is something wrong with my code

Comment: Strings representing dates can only be sorted reliably if they are in format `yyyy MM dd` (first `year` then `month` then `day`). If this is not possible you have to convert the date string to `Date`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to sort the string instead of the date. To properly sort it you first need to convert your `tSFDATE` string to `Date` and then sort it.

This should work with your existing array...

```swift
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss"

let sortedArray = trackingListArr.sorted { (lhs: trackingListArr, rhs: trackingListArr) -> Bool in
    // you can have additional code here
    return dateFormatter.date(from: lhs.tSFDATE)! > dateFormatter.date(from: rhs.tSFDATE)!
}
```

EDIT : Compact closure declaration

```swift
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss"

let sortedArray = trackingListArr.sorted { dateFormatter.date(from: $0.tSFDATE)! < dateFormatter.date(from: $1.tSFDATE)! }
```

EDIT 2 : Changed `dateFormat` to `"dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss"` to handle 24-hour time.

Comment: what do you mean by example

Comment: Whoops. That was the struct I used to test my code. I've fixed it now and updated the answer.

Comment: That's strange, do you get an error or does it sort incorrectly?

Comment: I edited my question and attached your code and screenshot

Comment: I changed "<" to and it worked, but in some times it gives me the below error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. can you help me to submit this answer as a correct

Comment: Aah, I see. It's sorting in ascending order, change the < to > inside the `sorted` closure.

Comment: so what about fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I got why this error appear, because server sending 24 hours format. so can you help @NSAdi

Comment: Just change `dateFormatter.dateFormat` to `"dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss"` as HH indicates 24-hour time. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162880/discussion-between-nsadi-and-ahmad-taalab).